# jQuery mobile button click handler firing twice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the code...simple (variables defined globally for now). First time I click it works as expected...second time howvere causes the event to fire twice consecutively which is now what I wanted...any ideas???

```
$(document).on("vclick", "#timer", function() {

  console.log(past_ts);
  if(past_ts === 0) {
    past_ts = new Date().getTime();
    $(this).text("Stop Set Timer");
  }
  else {
    curr_ts = new Date().getTime();
    diff_ts = ((curr_ts - past_ts) / 1000);

    past_ts = 0; // Reset timer

    $(this).text("Start Set Timer");

  }
});
```

Comment: are you wrapping code in `pageinit` or any other event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple. There's two ways I've been able to solve this problem.

1) Use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` after the opening function (second line).  Be sure to pass the event parameter.

```
$(document).on("vclick", "#timer", function(e) {
                                      //    ^ note this param
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  console.log(past_ts);
  if(past_ts === 0) {
    past_ts = new Date().getTime();
    $(this).text("Stop Set Timer");
  }
  else {
    curr_ts = new Date().getTime();
    diff_ts = ((curr_ts - past_ts) / 1000);

    past_ts = 0; // Reset timer

    $(this).text("Start Set Timer");

  }
});
```

**Documentation can be found here:** http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

OR

2) Try using `off().on()` technique.  This ensures that if you've already binded the behavior, it will unbind, then rebind.

```
$(document).off("vclick", "#timer").on("vclick", "#timer", function() {

  console.log(past_ts);
  if(past_ts === 0) {
    past_ts = new Date().getTime();
    $(this).text("Stop Set Timer");
  }
  else {
    curr_ts = new Date().getTime();
    diff_ts = ((curr_ts - past_ts) / 1000);

    past_ts = 0; // Reset timer

    $(this).text("Start Set Timer");

  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect...that works like a charm but why do I need to do that in the first place???

Comment: @Alex.Barylski when you call $.on(), you're binding an event to the ID.  Every time you call $.on() consecutively, it adds duplicate bindings (i.e. more than one).  By using e.stopImmediatePropagation(), it detects that there's already a binding assigned and prevents it from being added again.

Comment: OK i changed it to $("#timer").click(function(e)... and this still seems to be required...in any case it worked beautifully thank you :) now is there any way I can lock the screen from changing unless the "Stop" button is pressed :p

Comment: @Alex.Barylski Right, that's because $.click(handler) is just a shortcut for $.on('click', handler).  jQuery documentation is your friend on that one :).  Link:  http://api.jquery.com/click/